# Can Windows services write to HKEY_USERS?

Tags: windows, service, registry

I have a Windows program that installs a service.

I need to edit the HKEY_USERS registry key, however I am unsure if it is possible for services to do so.

Comment: If the service runs with adequate permissions, such as the SYSTEM account, then yes.  But you really shouldn't modify `HKEY_USERS` directly. What are you trying to accomplish?  There are APIs to access per-user Registry data, such as `RegOpenUserClassesRoot()`, `RegOpenCurrentUser()`, `LoadUserProfile()`, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. They can. As long as they run under the SYSTEM account.